# Get a JCheckBox working with an overriden Jtable getValueAt() function

Tags: java, swing, jtable, overriding, jcheckbox

I need a JTable to reflect a dynamic array's content so I had to override its getValueAt function. The problem is now JCheckboxes inside the table can't be toggled.

I've been looking for an answer since I though this to be quite an usual situation but I found no working solution so this is my last hope.

Back to the question, here's the test JFrame I coded:

```
package gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class CheckboxTest extends JFrame {
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable table;

    private Object[][] tableRows;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    CheckboxTest frame = new CheckboxTest();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public CheckboxTest() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        tableRows = new Object[5][2];
        for (int i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
            tableRows[i][0] = new Boolean(i % 2 == 0);
            tableRows[i][1] = "Test";
        }

        table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(tableRows, new String[] {"", "Name"}){
            @Override public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
                return (Class<?>) new Object[] { Boolean.class, String.class }[col];
            }

            @Override public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
                return tableRows[row][col];
            }
        });
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    }
}
```

Comment: value should be true/false, for more info to read Oracle tutorial - How to use Tables, 0/1 is in visual basic vba/e ...

Comment: I have read it more than once but I'm afraid it still seems confusing to me.

I've implemented Boolean class as you suggested but nothing seems to have changed. Could you please explain in more detail?

Comment: boolean clas is about to help DefaultTableModel to know desired value type, bu you have to set there value in form true/false, then JCheckBox is already visible in JTables view, maybe to search for isEditable, then you can change SELECTED/DESELECTED, and in DefaultTableModel will be stored true/false

Comment: Actually I've never used 0/1 values as booleans in the code. I suspect you misread the text.

Comment: right I can see `tableRows[i][0] = new Boolean(i % 2 == 0);`  in your code

Comment: That piece of code will return always "true" for odd indexes and "false" for even ones as you will confirm if you test it.

Comment: Don't screw with the JTable, this functionality is provided by the TableModel

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure, that the boolean colum is editable. Your subclass of the DefaultTableModel has to overwrite the method boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columIndex), wich should return true for columnIndex 0)

Comment: The OP isn't using a TableModel, that's most of the problem

Comment: Added to the code. Doesn't appear to change a thing.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I don't get what you mean.

Comment: *"Your subclass of the DefaultTableModel has to overwrite"* - The OP isn't using a table model, they've extended from the JTable directly...

Comment: The OP is extending the DefaultTableModel, but that is the problem they are extending it incorrectly.

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution myself. I just had to override DefaultTableModel's setValueAt function with

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
    tableRows[row][col] = value;
}
```

Comment: -1 that is not the proper solution. The DefaultTableModel uses a Vector of Vectors to store the data. There is no need for you to override either the getValueAt() method or the setValueAt() method. All you need to do is override the `getColumnClass()` method to return the class of the column so the table can use the proper renderer/editor.

Comment: I wouldn't override the functions for no reason. I need my table to relect a dynamic array which is modified in a form. The only element editable in the table is the JCheckBox to enable/disable the row. If you have a better way to do this I'm all ears @camickr .

Comment: You should never update the Array. The Array can be used ONCE to load data into the `DefaultTableModel`.  If you need to change the data you change the data in the TableModel not in the Array as you don't want to keep the data in two places. The DefaultTableModel has methods like setValueAt(...), addRow(...) etc. The TableModel will then invoke the appropriate fireXXX(...) methods to notify the table that the data has changed so the table can repaint itself. This is the same for all Swing components, you always make changes directly to the MODEL of the component.

Comment: I understand the opposite. By having an array and copying its values to the Model I have every value stored twice. By changing the Model into using the array I avoid duplicate data. How is this wrong?

Comment: `How is this wrong?` - the Array can be used to load data into the DefaultTableModel and then you should set the Array to null and never reference the Array again. All updates to the data should be done via methods of the TableModel. The DefaultTableModel already defines Vectors to hold the data. By defining a separate structure to hold the data in Arrays you have a confusing implementation of a TableModel. Also your implementation does NOT invoke the fireXXX() method when the data is changed. It is the responsibility of the model not the application code to notify the table when data changes.

Comment: If you want to create a custom TableModel with your own data storage then you should be extending AbstractTableModel in which case you will need to implement all the methods as demonstrated in the Swing tutorial on [Creating a Table Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)

Comment: bout the fire() function I removed it since it worked the same way with and without it. But I think I understand and I'll try doing it that way instead. Thanks for your help and sorry for being so dense.